# Show that $\{\emptyset, \mathbb N\}\cup\{O_n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ forms a topology where $O_n = \{n,n+1,n+2,\dots\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, solution-verification, natural-numbers

Show that $\mathcal U$ forms a topology on $X= \mathbb N$, where $$\mathcal U := \{\emptyset,\mathbb N \} \cup \{O_n : n\geq 1\},$$ where $O_n = \{n,n+1,n+2,\dots \}$.

i) Clearly the emptyset and $\mathbb N$ are open by construction.

ii) Let $\{O_\alpha : \alpha \in I\}$ be an arbitrary family of sets indexed over some $I\subseteq \mathbb N$. Then $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} O_\alpha = O_{\min I }$ because $O_j \subseteq O_k$ when $j \geq k$. Notably, if the family includes $O_1$ then the union is simply $\mathbb N$ itself.

iii) When $I$ is assumed to be a finite subset of $\mathbb N$, then the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} O_\alpha = O_{\max I}$ since $O_a \cap O_b = O_b$ when $b\geq a$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is mostly correct, although in both ii and iii, you need to account for the possibility that the empty set is part of your collection. (which is easy to do)

Comment: Here $\mathcal{O}_n$ is a decreasing sequence of sets. Finite intersection is the last element and countable union is the first element.

Comment: @LostinSpace Is this not what I wrote?

Comment: You never know when you've made a careless error, so I don't see a problem with verifying that.

Comment: Well. Never mind. It's just a suggestion.

Comment: I would note that normally you must check that an arbitrary (meaning possibly uncountable) union of open sets is open. Yet, (ii) is still correct because there are only countably many open sets in this proposed topology anyway. Nice observation!

Comment: Note: you only have to single out $\varnothing$ in your description of the topology as $\mathbb{N}$ is one of your $O_n$ (either $n=0$ or $n=1$, depending on your definition of the naturals).